# Test for the comparison of multiple paired samples

Tags: r, paired-data, friedman-test

I have a set of patients where radiographs from the neck were taken at different locations (1,2,3) from the left and from the right side. These radiographs were then scored using an ordinal scale. The mean of these scores was then used as overall score (in the following "score" is the overall score).

Using Kendall's tau I have found that the scores were not independent between the left and the right side (it is likely that abnormalities on one side will generate defects on the other side). On the other hand, the different locations are assumed to be independent.

I now want to see if there are any significant differences between the scores obtained at the different locations. I want to use Friedman's test for that (because `L_X` and `R_X` are not independent, so I cannot use Kruskal-Wallis). Is this the right test to pick?

Here is an example data.frame in wide format, for a better understanding:

```
Patient        L_1        R_1       L_2   R_2       L_3        R_3
      1  0.3333333  0.3333333  1.1666667  0.5  1.166667  0.6666667
      2  0.8333333  0.3333333  0.8333333  1.0  1.666667  1.3333333
    ...        ...        ...        ...  ...       ...        ...
```

Another form of the model.matrix could be:

```
Patient          1          2         3
    1_L  0.3333333  1.1666667  1.166667
    1_R  0.3333333  0.5000000  0.666667
    2_L  0.8333333  0.8333333  1.666667
    2_R  0.3333333  1.0000000  1.666667
    ...        ...        ...       ...
```

But then the patients would not be independent...

Comment: One way to deal with this would be to apply multiple paired comparisons with [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction). I also believe Kruskal-Wallis is robust enough to handle paired samples.

Comment: It sounds like Friedman is a possibility, with Patient used as a block and 1L, 1R, 2L, 2R, 3L, 3R used as the treatments.  This ignores the tie between the left and right sides in a patient.  A two-sample paired rank-sum test could then be used as a post-hoc test to compare among treatments.

Comment: However, I would advise you look into ordinal regression in R (*ordinal* package).  You would be able to use a mixed-effects model with Patient as a random effect.  You wouldn't need to average the scores.  Also, you could consider L/R as a separate variable from Location.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I will probably use Kruskal Wallis then, to keep it simple (this is just a really small part of my project). But I will keep the ordinal regression in mind, it will probably be useful in an other part of my project.